# Chrome destroys css with forcing https?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, http, https

Hya folks,

After updating Chrome to the latest version (44.0.2403.89 m) it has problems showing my (wordpress) website correctly.

First of all when I try to go on my site, ie domain.com, it tries to use https instead of http and it gives an error that the connection is not secure / private (NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).

Currently I am NOT using https, ssl on the page and have no plans to use it in the near future.

Before updating chrome I didn't get any kind of warning like that while accessing my page. So first question would be if there is a way to disable / remove this kind of warning from chrome. It would really confuse new visitors accessing my page.

While accessing my page with HTTPS (after seeing the chrome's warning and still proceeding to the page) it actually shows a page from my hosting provider (cause I dont have the hosting package with https enabled, it costs more). So it completely goes to the wrong page if the user just tries to access the site without typing in the "www" part (just the domainname ie: domain.com).

So if i currently want to view my webpage I need to type in WWW.domain.com, while doing so it goes to the http version of the page (winning). But now I've got a new problem, the CSS files are not loading because it tries to access all the css files via HTTPS protocol.

Before updating chrome, the website worked just fine. The exact same thing also happened to one of my other wordpress sites on an other domain with a different hosting provider :/ It gets me really worried.

Really looking for help... if you guys need any additional information, please let me know :)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can i get your sites link please to check

Comment: Clear your browser cache and history fully.restart crhome and try again

Comment: tried clearing cache, history etc.. doesn't help, also the problem exisct in incognito mode.

Comment: I keep banging my head, still havent found the problem :/ thinking that maybe some kind of plugin can cause this and the only similarity between my 2 sites is that they both are using WPML (deleted & disabled on the first site - oy8x4az (tinurl) tho) and Woocommerce

Comment: I would uninstall Chrome mate and reinstall it.

Comment: check your wordpress site url and make sure its not https and also in woocomerce you are not forcing https which i dont think you are as i dont get hit with it anywhere in your site.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was WooCommerce plugin.
I found a solution in here:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/site-broken-in-chrome-ssl-issue/page/2

Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a ton!

Yup! It was the WooCommerce that was causing this. Somebody suggested yesterday (he deleted his answer already) to update WooCommerce and it did the trick aswell. But at the moment this solution is best for me cause I haven't updated WooCommerce a while and the update broke my site. So your suggested workaround is much better for the time being  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also temprorary fix this issue without updating the plugin by comment out these lines of code in `plugins\woocommerce\woocommerce.php`:

```php
if ( ! isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) && ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_HTTPS'] ) ) { 
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HTTPS']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you found a fix yet. But I had the exact same problem and I saw this morning that there is another Chrome update. So after the update my sites seem to work again without forcing the https protocol.

Version at the moment: 44.0.2403.107 m

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Just go Into Your WP-Theme -> Themes -> your Theme -> functions.php

add This Line : $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = false;

Note: If you don't want SSL

Thanks :)